# How to change order of tabs in adminhtml catalog product edit in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I create tab Opinion in adminhtml catalog product page.

I want that my tab 'Opinion' was first in list of tabs.

**app/code/local/Fishpig/Customtabs/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Tab.php**

class Fishpig_Customtabs_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Tab 
extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface {

```
public function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();

    $this->setTemplate('customtabs/catalog/product/tab.phtml');
}

public function getTabLabel()
{
    return $this->__('Opinion');
}
 public function getTabTitle()
{
    return $this->__('Click here to view your custom tab content');
}

public function canShowTab()
{
    return true;
}

public function isHidden()
{
    return false;
}
```

**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/customtabs.xml**

*

```
<layout>
    <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
<reference name="product_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <name>opinion</name>
                <block>customtabs/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
            </action>enter code here
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
</layout>
```

*

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8IzBo.png).

Answer (score 0):

If you want your tab at the first in Admin Catalog Product Add Or Edit page

then you need to do these Steps

1: Override this File

```
<global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_edit_tabs>Namespace_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs</catalog_product_edit_tabs>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
```

Step 2 : in the file

there is one function named : `_prepareLayout`

override that in your module file

and add the tab after this code

```
$product = $this->getProduct();

        if (!($setId = $product->getAttributeSetId())) {
            $setId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('set', null);
        }
```

add this code

```
$this->addTab('opinion', array(
                'label'     => Mage::helper('core')->__('Opinion'),
                'url'       => $this->getUrl('module/controller/opinion', array('_current' => true)),
                'class'     => 'ajax',
            ));
```

Step 3 : in controller create one function opinion and set your template file there with `$this->setTemplate('customtabs/catalog/product/tab.phtml');`

let me know if you need more help

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I add how you write, but I have another problem.

Comment: After adding tab all standart tabs (General,Prices,...)are not displayed like on this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/xUkIX.png

Comment: can you view source of the page and check any fatal error is there and let me know the error

Comment: Thank you, I decided my problem. I  wanted to make a tab at the first in the list or set active. I found option -    'active'    => true .

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `addTabAfter` method instead

```
    <action method="addTabAfter">
        <name>opinion</name>
        <block>customtabs/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
        <after></after>
    </action>
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine after which tab you want add you cutom tab you need in your file
**app/code/local/Fishpig/Customtabs/Block/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Tab.php**
add such method:

```
public function getAfter()
{
    return 'group_32'; // Name of tab after which you want add your tab
}
```

group_32 it's name of General tab in my case.